# copying a file doesn't work

Tags: swift, swift2, nsfilemanager

I copied a file like this:

```
let fontFolderPath = "/Users/meeeee/Library/Fonts/"
    let allFontsPath = "/Users/meeeee/Desktop/all_fonts/Pacifico.ttf"
    var error:NSDictionary?

    @IBAction func changeFonts(sender: AnyObject) {
        do{
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtPath(allFontsPath, toPath: fontFolderPath)

        }
        catch{

        }
}
```

No errors are thrown, but upon manually checking `/Users/meeeee/Library/Fonts/` the Pacifico.ttf isn't there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you put that code in playground? Because they are sandboxed...

Comment: No, I use it in a Mac app

Comment: There is an error that is thrown, you never process it.

Comment: The syntax in the duplicate link is for Swift 1 but the idea is the same, as Martin R said in his deleted comment: the destination path should include the filename.